# Very simple Razor requirement but can't find any simple examples

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

I want to create an HTML email from a Razor template. I'd like to do this using the Razor engine. I have created a simple Razor template and the corresponding model to supply my Razor template with data. I can't for the life of me find any simple examples of how to combine these together to create an HTML email.

The Razor API is bewildering and I'm not sure where to start.

Can anyone provide me with some very simple code examples of how to create an HTML email using a simple Razor template and model.

Comment: I came across that but the example uses a third-party nuget package. I'd prefer to use raw Razor if possible as I don't want to have to rely on a third-party package for what (should be) something pretty straight forward.

Comment: The requirement is straight forward enough and is what Razor was designed for. Let me re-phrase that. The solution "ought" to be straight forward :)